# how subject work in rspec in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I recently learn about rspec test in rails and as following the link https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/subject/explicit-subject that said "The `subject` is memoized within an example but not across examples " with the code below:

```
RSpec.describe Array do
  # This uses a context local variable. As you can see from the
  # specs, it can mutate across examples. Use with caution.
  element_list = [1, 2, 3]

  subject { element_list.pop }

  it "is memoized across calls (i.e. the block is invoked once)" do
    expect {
      3.times { subject }
    }.to change{ element_list }.from([1, 2, 3]).to([1, 2])
    expect(subject).to eq(3)
  end

  it "is not memoized across examples" do
    expect{ subject }.to change{ element_list }.from([1, 2]).to([1])
    expect(subject).to eq(2)
  end
end
```

Can anyone explain to me:

- why **3.times { subject }** exec only once **element_list.pop**
- the sentence '**it "is not memoized across examples"**' meant **element_list** still [1, 2, 3] but in this example, it is only [1, 2] ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, by way of clarification, the RSpec `subject` helper is nothing more than a special case of RSpec's `let` helper. Using `subject { element_list.pop }` is equivalent to `let(:subject) { element_list.pop }`.

Like any other `let`, `subject` is evaluated once per example. If `subject` has a value, that value is returned without re-evaluation. The general term for this is "memoization."

Ruby's `||=` operator does the same thing. It says, "if a value exists in that variable, return the value, otherwise evaluate the expression, assign it to the variable, and return the value." You can see this concept in action in the console with this example:

```
>> element_list = [1, 2, 3]
>> subject ||= element_list.pop
=> 3
>> element_list
=> [1, 2]
>> subject ||= element_list.pop
=> 3
>> element_list
=> [1, 2]
>> subject
=> 3
```

The fact that `subject` is not memoized across examples means that its value is reset when a new example is executed. So for your next `it` block, `subject` will start out unassigned and its expression will be re-evaluated when it is first used in that next `it` block.